# Non-system HDD, Windows 10 is freezing, not responding and slow

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, backup, freeze

I have recently built my long waited new PC ([specs](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/J66ZQq)).

But I have made a very bad decision and bought Seagate 4TB HDD, which I found out was SMR drive. It is really slow and it takes ages to write small files (I mostly work with small files).

Then I bought Samsung Evo 970 1TB SSD so I could store my projects and small files there, the problem seems solved.

I now know that SMR drives are good for backups (like tapedrive) and decided to install AOMEI Backupper and scheduled periodic (once a day) backup my 1TB SSD to 4TB HDD.

I do not know why my Windows occasionally freezes and becomes slow when the backup process is active. I have separate SSD (500 GB Evo Plus) for system and that SMR drive is not involved in the system (not using anywhere, except backup).

p.s. Here is the [screenshot](https://pasteboard.co/INB9aX4.png) when AOMEI is performing the backup.

How I can solve or investigate this problem?

UPD: Windows 10 1909 (18363.535)

Comment: I think you should schedule the backup to run when you're not using the computer, or replace the SMR drive with a [SSHD](https://www.amazon.com/Seagate-FireCuda-Gaming-Accelerated-Performance/dp/B07H2F3741/ref) that is a normad HDD combined with a NAND flash module.

Comment: @spike_66 I am using SSHD as a daily storage (for games, downloads and etc), but the problem is why HDD that is not used by system freezes system so much?

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood, but don't you use the SMR HDD for backup? If it's so this is what slows down your system.